# Winforms: Acceder a un control desde otro hilo

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Para acceder a un control de un formulario desde otro hilo qué técnica se recomienda, ¿`Delegate con el invoke` o la clase `BackgroundWorker`?

Caso 1 *Delegate con el invoke*:

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

private void SetText(string text){
    if( textBox1.InvokeRequired ){
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }else{
        this.textBox1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Caso 2 *clase BackgroundWorker*:

```
private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;  

private void setTextBackgroundWorkerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();  
}  

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {  
    this.textBox1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Esta pregunta es basada en opiniones, depende el caso de uso de lo que requieras hacer, que intentas hacer exactamente?, solo necesitas cambiar el texto a un `TextBox` ?, si es así bastaría con hacer: `Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
        () => textBox1.Text = TuTexto;
    ));` De este modo te evitas usar un montón de código

Comment: modificar el mismo textbox desde dos hilos diferentes? que miedo

Comment: Miedo? quién dijo miedo? ;) Básicamente tengo que pasar una función a cada n hilos a la cual van a llamar cada hilo n veces por segundo y que se encargará de hacer el sumatorio de todas las llamadas por segundo y pintarlo en un control. Utilizaremos lock dentro de la función para que en cada llamada no se pise el sumatorio.

Comment: Y ¿podría apreciarse alguna diferencia o performance entre?: Invoke(new MethodInvoker( () => textBox1.Text = TuTexto; ))  y Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => textBox1.Text = TuTexto;);

Comment: BackgroundWorker? habiendo métodos asíncronos que es lo que, después de .net 4.5, se recomienda utilizar? la verdad estás complicando bastante tu código, al rato no vas a saber que cosa cambia que cosa.

Comment: La frase "al rato no vas a saber que cosa cambia que cosa." me parece demasiado categórica.